# add css style to iframe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add CSS style to iframe in React.
The code works fine when I didn't use React.
But when I add the code to React, it crashes and shows an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'head' of null

I found that I can access `contentDocument.head` and append child to it if I didn't use React.

My code:

```
const selection = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
const iframes = Array.prototype.slice.call(selection);
for (let x in iframes) {
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  const css = `*{ color: red; }`;
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

  iframes[x].contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

But in React, the `contentDocument` is `null`. strange.

Is there anything I am missing?